# Second order effects of something

Tags: terminology, perturbation-theory

When physicists talk about second order effects, e.g. "Second order effects of elasticity/plasticity in solids" what do they mean by this?

Comment: I might be wrong, as it depends on the system. You say _effects_ where I have used the idea of   approximation, because that is what I am familiar with, but with material sciences, it may mean something different. There is no rush to accept until you are happy with an answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory is a generalisation of the idea.

Comment: Well, when talking about elasticity of a crystal, the same principle as you described is applicable if you think of it as particles connected by springs.

Comment: Hey coward, leave a comment if you downvote

Comment: Well, personally, I wouldn't take any   d/v quite **that** seriously.  It's not personal, I guess someone thought you might have mentioned any reference to where you looked, before you asked the question,   which I think has some validity. Seriously, the golden rule on this site is learn and move on. Why do you think I picked the username I  have now: )

Comment: How can I learn if I'm not told what I did wrong. I'm not taking it seriously, it was probably some kid...

Comment: Yeah, I know, (and agree) with you, that comments would be a help. But to me anyway, the reason is obvious....Will you the remember the d/V  in two days time?... nah!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a function that describes a phenomenon, such as the equilibrium position of a vertically hanging pendulum, and you expand that function in a Taylor series, you can view terms with $x^2$ included as second order effects.

Often, it indicates  the insignificance of  higher terms, in terms of accuracy, that is  it's a cutoff point where the terms diminish with increasing powers  of $x$.

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing concepts, but AFAIK often times the effects of higher order terms are also referred to as "non-linear behaviour", due to the $x^n$ no longer being a line if $n \gt 1$, making the responses vary in ways that may not seem intuitive.

Comment: @JMac Yes, and a Wikipedia page refers to that. Sorry I didn't note the page, but effects **would** make sense in the context of non linearity, but the OP seems happy that it describes his/ her problem.

Comment: Oh yeah, this definitely does describe it.  I just was adding that some people might refer to it differently, and that the $x^2$ factor plays into it.  Potentially mitigating another question down the line.

Answer (score 2):

That terminology arises in the following situation: we want to compute some quantity $f(x)$ that depends on some parameter $x$. We have some information about the point $x=x_0$, such as the value of $f$ and its first derivatives. We can then usually approximate 
\begin{equation}
f(x)\simeq f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2+\cdots,
\end{equation}
for $x$ sufficiently near $x_0$.

In general, the effects calculated from the term with $n$-power of $x-x_0$ are said to be of $n$-th order. One may go further and extend this to any situation in which we are able to produce increasingly good approximations.

Answer (score 0):

In nonlinear anisotropic elastoplasticity, you can express the stress components $\sigma_{ij}$ as:

$$\sigma_{ij} = \sum_{k,l} C_{ijkl}(\varepsilon_{kl}-p_{kl}) + \sum_{k,l,m,n} S_{ijklmn}(\varepsilon_{kl}-p_{kl})(\varepsilon_{mn}-p_{mn}) + O(\varepsilon^3)$$

where $\varepsilon_{ij}$ are the total strain components, and $p_{ij}$ the plastic strain components. So, the second order effects are due to the constants $S_{ijklmn}$.